# Updating @ManyToMany in JPA errors with "parent key not found"

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, many-to-many

I have a repository method that does  something like this:

`Person` and `Dog` are the entities. `person` and `dog` are method parameters.

```
    Dog dog = entityManager.find(Dog.class, dogId);

    if (dog== null) {
        // creates dog
        dog = entityManager.persist(dog);
    }

    person.addDog(dog);
    entityMananger.merge(person);
```

Person and dog have a many-to-many releationship. I believe the issue is that the insert statement for dog isn't executed first.

```
ORA-02291 parent key not found
```

This is from a EJB 3.1 bean, using container managed transactions.

Comment: could you show the generated queries?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that is not your real code, as it would get a null-pointer exception as dog is null.

Why are you merging the person?  Where does the person come from.  If you got the person from the same EntityManager you don't need to call merge.  You might somehow be getting two copies of the dog.

It should insert the dog first, and the join table last.  What JPA provider are you using?

Please include the full exception, and the SQL log.

Comment: Yes, it is correct that it isn't the real code. Both `person` and `dog` are arguments in the repository method. They are invoked from a client. Hibernate is the persistence provider.